# How to avoid "cannot find implementation or library stub" when mypy is installed via mason in nvim

Tags: mypy, neovim

I am using Neovim and installed `mypy` with `mason`, and I also configured it using `null-nvim`:

```lua
local sources = { null_ls.builtins.diagnostics.mypy }
```

Here, `mypy`, installed by `mason`, in fact, is installed in a separate virtual environment under `~/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/mypy`. It seems that `mypy` will always raise warnings "cannot find implementation or library stub" if the third-party library is installed in another environment.

For example, I activated `myenv` where `openai` is installed, and then I opened a Python file using Neovim:

[image]

On the other hand, if I installed `mypy` inside `myenv`, then everything works well. But this method requires me to install every copy of `mypy` for every virtual environment. How to avoid the warning message when I installed it via `mason`?

---

### Update

> For example, if you are running your code in a virtualenv, make sure to install and use `mypy` within the virtualenv. Alternatively, if you want to use a globally installed `mypy`, set the `--python-executable` command line flag to point the Python interpreter containing your installed third party packages.

It seems that `mypy` is not able to detect the current virutalenv I am using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a workaround way in both Linux and macOS:

```lua
nls.builtins.diagnostics.mypy.with({
    extra_args = function()
    local virtual = os.getenv("VIRTUAL_ENV") or os.getenv("CONDA_PREFIX") or "/usr"
    return { "--python-executable", virtual .. "/bin/python3" }
    end,
}),
```

The code above detects virutalenv first, and otherwise, it will use default `/usr/bin/python3` as the `--python-executable`.

Comment: Where to put this? Is order important?

Comment: You can put it into any location that nvim will load it. For example, the convention place is `lua/plugins/xxx.lua`. Also note that `null-nvim` is deprecated, and I have switched to "nvimtools/none-ls.nvim". But luckily, those two plugins share similar configs.

Comment: Obvious note: this should be placed in the opts.sources of the null-ls package. I took a long time to figure that out lol.